# ¿Como guardar un audio Streaming?

Tags: java

Muy buenas, no se si mi pregunta esta bien formulada, pero tengo una aplicación en la cual reproduzco un audio almacenado en mi hosting, lo que quiero es poder guardarla, he buscado de todo y no encuentro manera para guardar.

Tengo un listview que lo lleno con una base de datos remota,

cuando doy clic en un item de mi lista manda a llamar a la siguiente funcion enviandole el url de donde tengo almacenada la musica que reproduce

```
public void reproducir(String YT) {

    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
    }
    try {
        data = Uri.parse(YT);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), data);
        mp.start();
        ActSeekBar.start();
        sb.setMax(0);
        try {
        } catch (Exception e) {
            sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }


}
```

Comment: Hola buenos días, para que enriquezca tu pregunta te recomiendo que coloques el código o lo que has podido lograr hasta ahora.

Comment: Gracias, es mi primer pregunta y no sabia como hacerla, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Podría ser de tu utilidad la respuesta  a la sig pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166187/is-there-a-way-of-recording-audio-of-streaming-broadcast-from-a-webpage

Comment: Lo que necesito es un botón que me ayude a descargar la música que se esta reproduciendo, el boton y lo tengo, solo no se como indicarle que me tiene que descargar el archivo de audio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas tardes, encontre la solucion a mi pregunta en el siguiente enlace: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog